# Select Peak Hour Day wise data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to write a query that returns peak hours of count day wise. Let Suppose I have peak count at 1PM on monday and peak count at 10AM on Tuesday then output of the query should looks like

```
Day      Peak_Hour     Count
Monday   1             243423
Tuesday  3             224534
Saturday 18            219484
```

and so on.

I have tried query it returns overall peak hours day wise. Days should not be repeated.

```
select distinct dayname(Tr_Date) as Day_Name, T_Hour, sum(CNT) as Count
from In_Out_Cnt_Direction
group by dayname(Tr_Date), T_Hour
order by sum(CNT) desc;
```

Output is:
[image]

I just want unique seven day with highest peak hours count. Return data is correct but I want just seven days peak hours count from monday to sunday not duplicate day.

Comment: Please give more detail, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Maybe your table has a column like `t_day` and using `where > now() -  INTERVAL 7 DAY`. Maybe a simple window function could also help but first we need details.

Comment: I don't have t_day column, I am extracting day from Tr_Date. I want to get only distinct seven days and its peak hours along with count.

Comment: Stll you need to edit your question according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).